# How to use FFmpeg Command for Reverse Video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i am use to FFmpeg library in android for reverse video. I can dump images from video but how to reverse all images and make video. See [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) link that from i am use to library in my gradle.. Library is `compile 'com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid:0.2.5'` i can use some of command and some are not. i use command as like below

`-i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -an -qscale 1 /storage/emulated/0/ffimg/revi%06d.jpg`

above command use for dump images from video. i can't use command as liki `$ffmpeg` , `$sox` and `$cat`

i have referred many link but not success in see below some links...

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214327/how-can-i-reverse-a-video-clip

http://jiaxihu.blogspot.in/2012/05/reverse-video-clip-with-ffmpeg.html

So please help me and give me solution. if other library available then suggest me. thanks advance

Answer (score 67):

FFmpeg has a [reverse video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#reverse) and [reverse audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#areverse).

For video only:

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -vf reverse reversed.mp4
```

For audio and video:

```
ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse reversed.mp4
```

This filter buffers the **entire** clip. For larger files, segment the file, reverse each segment and then concat the reversed segments. Remember that you have to concat the reversed segments in the *reverse order*!

Answer (score 11):

@Gyan is correct. You can reverse a video using `ffmegs` built in [reverse video filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#reverse):

```bash
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf reverse video_reversed.mp4
```

However this is incredibly memory intensive. I wont go into details but it has to do with the video is saved in a compressed format. To reverse it, it needs basically load each frame of the video into memory.

Therefor for any reasonably sized video (> 10 minutes) you are going to have a tough time using the above command. Thus to complete @Gyan's answer. Here is how to segment the video, reverse each part, and then concatenate them again.

You can first segment a video into `300` second chunks using:

```bash
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 300 -reset_timestamps 1 video_%03d.mp4
```

This will output a bunch of video files named `video_000.mp4`, `video_001.mp4` etc. Next you need to reverse each of these segments. You can either do that manually using the original reverse command, or you can use the loop provided below.

**NOTE**: Make sure you remove the original video `video.mp4` from the folder before using the loop below (otherwise you are back to the start).

Alternatively for long videos you might want to use a loop. This loop looks for all `mp4` files in the current directory and reverses each of them:

**To reverse only the video but not the audio:**

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i $f -vf reverse ${f/.mp4/_reversed.mp4}
done
```

**To reverse the video and audio:**

```bash
for f in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i $f -vf reverse -af areverse ${f/.mp4/_reversed.mp4}
done
```

You will now have a set of reversed segments med `video_000_reversed.mp4`, `video_001_reversed.mp4` etc. The final command concatenates them into a single video. To do that we need a text file with all the files we want to concatenate. You can automatically create this text file using the following:

```bash
for f in ./SegmentedVideos/*_reversed.mp4;  do 
    echo file \'$f\' > tmp.txt
    cat fileList.txt >> tmp.txt
    rm fileList.txt
    mv tmp.txt fileList.txt
done
```

At this point you should have a text file `fileList.txt` that contains the video files in reverse order like this:

```
file './video_XXX_reversed.mp4'
...
file './video_001_reversed.mp4'
file './video_000_reversed.mp4'
```

Then all we need to do is concatenate everything:

```bash
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i fileList.txt -c copy final_revered_video.mp4
```

Comment: I tried this, got as far as the last step, but at that point got the `moov atom not found` error.